# Prevent sort from sorting filenames instead of greped content

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

In a script, I want to get a variable from find `grep` and sort to display it with echo on screen. The variable looks like:

```
OUTPUT="$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'filename' | xargs grep -o -m 1 "string" | sort -r)"
```

Find should search for some files with the same name in folder `xyz`.
Pipe them to grep to search these files for every first matching string in it.
Then sort should sort descending.

This works pretty well except of no matter what I try sort will always sort by the filenames but it should sort by the matching strings grep has found.
This is what the output looks like

```
/file3:111
/file2:666
/file1:333
```

And this is what I wanted echo to display no matter what the filename is:

```
 /file2:666
 /file1:333
 /file3:111
```

With `grep -h` I get the result I want but I also need the filenames to be displayed as additional info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `sort` which part of its input you want to sort after. That's what the switch `-k` (for "key") is for. Let's say you have a list like

```
/file3 111
/file2 666
/file1 333
```

You want to sort after the second field, so you need `-k 2`:

```
sort -r -k 2
```

By default, `sort` separates the fields by a "non-blank to blank transition", or between every non-whitespace character which is followed by a whitespace character. In your case, you separate the fields of your input with a `:`. So have to tell `sort` that as well, with the switch `-t`:

```
sort -r -k 2 -t ':'
```

As a more general remark, in a pipeline (multiple commands chained together with `|`), a later command doesn't know how its input came to be. So thinking about it like "`sort` needs to look at what came from `grep` and not from `find`" is probably not that helpful ;) `sort` only knows what its input looks like, not who played what part in the construction of the input.

Comment: thx @Henning Kockerbeck I already tried with -k but the -t ':' does the trick!